# Confirm Express Checkout on PayPal via PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal

This question asked before but didn't got any answer.Maybe things have been changed.

When you click the Express Checkout PayPal button on any webshop, it redirects you to a specific paypal login link, for paying the order.

I have been searching high and low for 3 weeks for a simple paypal php curl script that logs you in from this step, and confirms the payment, but have not been able to find anything.

I found out it is not possible to use the API for this, so its gotta be done by CURL.

I'm asking for this because I run a dropshipping website, and would like to automate certain steps, like placing and paying orders. A working code for this would help not just me, but all looking to automate buying in some form.

Thank's!

Comment: When you say "script that logs you in from this step" are you asking to log a buyer into PayPal.com? I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes.That is what I asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't log the buyer into PayPal when you redirect them to the site. The buyer has to enter their own account credentials themselves.

If you wanted to bill a buyer without requiring they log into PayPal each time you would need to use billing agreements (reference transactions) through Express Checkout. If you set up a billing agreement with a buyer you can charge a previously successful sale to bill them again for a different amount.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with Express Checkout, especially since nobody will ever enter the paypal details on your website (that is the entire point of paypal).

You can use either preapproved payments (buyers preappove payments being taken out of their account up to a certain ceiling), or reference transactions (you reference a new transaction to an older transaction. PayPal will then use the billing details of this earlier transaction to bill the user).

Preapproved payments is part of Adaptive Payments. Documentation is at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

You can find more details about Reference Transactions at https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns

Note: Reference Transactions needs to be enabled on your account. This API call is not open to everyone due to the potential for abuse, so you may want to look into whether you're eligible for it before you start working on a full integation with it.
You can find more info here :https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Does-Paypal-have-a-quot-Token-Payments-quot-concept/td-p/325794

Also google "token payments" as that is what you need and most payment gateways usually support them.